# Java Regular Expressions Capturing Groups

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to split width and height from this String

```
String imgStyle = "width: 300px; height: 295px;";
int width = 300; // i want to get this value
int height = 295; // i want to get this value
```

I tried a lot of regular expressions but i can't get them.

```
String imgStyle = "width: 300px; height: 295px;";

int imgHeight = 0;
int imgWidth = 0;

Pattern h = Pattern.compile("height:([0-9]*);");
Pattern w = Pattern.compile("width:([0-9]*);");

Matcher m1 = h.matcher(imgStyle);
Matcher m2 = w.matcher(imgStyle);

if (m1.find()) {
    imgHeight = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(2));
}

if (m2.find()) {
    imgWidth = Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2));
}
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far

Comment: `I tried a lot of regular expressions but i can't get them` Please, post your attempts, so that we can see them and tell you what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
String imgStyle = "width: 300px; height: 295px;";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("width:\\s+(\\d+)px;\\s+height:\\s+(\\d+)px;");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(imgStyle);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("width is " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("height is " + m.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String imgStyle = "width: 300px; height: 295px;";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("width: (?<width>\\d++)px; height: (?<height>\\d++)px;");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(imgStyle);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group("width"));
        System.out.println(matcher.group("height"));
    }
}
```

Simply replace the number part with `(\\d++)` - i.e. match and capture the digits.

I have used named groups for clarity.

Comment: Why `\\d++` instead of `\\d+`?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal it's [possesive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). Prevents any backtracking.

Comment: Ah, nice read. So, the longer the match, the more the performance hit on any backtracking. +1.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is wrong:

```
Pattern h = Pattern.compile("height:([0-9]*);");
Pattern w = Pattern.compile("width:([0-9]*);");
```

In your string, there is a space between the colon and the number, and you also have `px` before the semicolon, so it should be:

```
Pattern h = Pattern.compile("height: ([0-9]*)px;");
Pattern w = Pattern.compile("width: ([0-9]*)px;");
```

Or better:

```
Pattern h = Pattern.compile("height:\\s+(\\d+)px;");
Pattern w = Pattern.compile("width:\\s+(\\d+)px;");
```

You should also capture group 1, not group 2:

```
if (m1.find()) {
    imgHeight = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(1));
}

if (m2.find()) {
    imgWidth = Integer.parseInt(m2.group(1));
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/0ryp6X)

Answer (score 0):

Just add space before the digits:

```
Pattern h = Pattern.compile("height:\\s*([0-9]+)");
Pattern w = Pattern.compile("width:\\s*([0-9]+)");
```